# Practical Scheme Programming

Tags: scheme, racket, continuations

It's been a few months since I've touched Scheme and decided to implement a command line income partitioner using Scheme.

My initial implementation used plain recursion over the continuation, but I figured a continuation would be more appropriate to this type of program. I would appreciate it if anyone (more skilled with Scheme than I) could take a look at this and suggest improvements. I'm that the multiple `(display...` lines is an ideal opportunity to use a macro as well (I just haven't gotten to macros yet).

```
(define (ab-income)
  (call/cc
   (lambda (cc)
     (let
         ((out (display "Income: "))
          (income (string->number (read-line))))
       (cond
         ((<= income 600)
          (display (format "Please enter an amount greater than $600.00~n~n"))
          (cc (ab-income)))
         (else
          (let
              ((bills    (* (/ 30 100) income))
               (taxes    (* (/ 20 100) income))
               (savings  (* (/ 10 100) income))
               (checking (* (/ 40 100) income)))
            (display (format "~nDeduct for bills:---------------------- $~a~n" (real->decimal-string bills 2)))
            (display (format "Deduct for taxes:---------------------- $~a~n" (real->decimal-string taxes 2)))
            (display (format "Deduct for savings:-------------------- $~a~n" (real->decimal-string savings 2)))
            (display (format "Remainder for checking:---------------- $~a~n" (real->decimal-string checking 2))))))))))
```

Invoking `(ab-income)` asks for input and if anything below 600 is provided it (from my understanding) returns `(ab-income)` at the `current-continuation`. My first implementation (as I said earlier) used plain-jane recursion. It wasn't bad at all either but I figured every return call to `(ab-income)` if the value was below 600 kept expanding the function.

(please correct me if that apprehension is incorrect!)

Comment: I think you have 3 `)))` too much.

Comment: It is a correct program, for some reason stackoverflow was removing input when I put the code into <pre> blocks; I just removed those and space each line by 4...

Comment: @lxmatus: I see. Text inside `<pre>` is still interpreted as HTML, so the stuff between `<=` and `>` will be "hidden". Always indent by 4 spaces (use the "101010" button on the toolbar).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a continuation.  According to the standard, Scheme will always perform [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).  A tail call is a function call which is in the final position in a function; after that call is run, nothing else will happen.  In that situation, we don't need to preserve the activation record we're currently in; as soon as the function we call returns, we'll just pop it.  Consequently, a tail call reuses the current activation record.  As an example, consider this:

```
(define (some-function x y)
  (preprocess x)
  (combine (modified x) y))
(some-function alpha beta)
```

When we call `some-function`, we allocate space for its activation record on the stack: local variables, parameters, etc.  We then call `(preprocess x)`.  Since we need to return to `some-function` and keep processing, we have to preserve `some-function`'s activation record, and so we push a new activation record on for `preprocess`.  Once that returns, we pop `preprocess`'s stack frame and keep going.  Next, we need to evaluate `modified`; the same thing has to happen, and when `modified` returns, its result is passed to `combine`.  One would think we'd need to create a new activation record, run `combine`, and then return this to `some-function`—but `some-function` doesn't need to do anything with that result but return it!  Thus, we overwrite the current activation record, but leave the return address alone; when `combine` returns, then, it will return its value to exactly what was waiting for it.  Here, `(combine (modified x) y)` is a tail call, and evaluating it doesn't require an extra activation record.

This is how you can implement loops in Scheme, for instance:

```
(define (my-while cond body)
  (when (cond)
    (body)
    (my-while cond body)))

(let ((i 0))
  (my-while (lambda () (< i 10))
            (lambda () (display i) (newline) (set! i (+ i 1)))))
```

Without tail call optimization, this would be inefficient, and would potentially overflow with a long-running loop building up lots of calls to `my-while`.  However, thanks to tail call optimization, the recursive call to `my-while cond body` is a jump, and allocates no memory, making this as efficient as iteration.

Secondly, you don't need any macros here.  While you can abstract out the `display` block, you can do this with a plain function.  Macros allow you, on some level, to change the syntax of the language—add your own sort of `define`, implement some type-case construct which doesn't evaluate all its branches, etc.  Of course, it's all still s-expressions, but the semantics are no longer simply "evaluate the arguments and call the function".  Here, however, function-call semantics are all you need.

With that said, I think this is how I'd implement your code:

```
(require (lib "string.ss"))

(define (print-report width . nvs)
  (if (null? nvs)
    (void)
    (let ((name  (car  nvs))
          (value (cadr nvs)))
      (display (format "~a:~a $~a~n"
                       name
                       (make-string (- width (string-length name) 2) #\-)
                       (real->decimal-string value 2)))
      (apply print-report width (cddr nvs)))))

(define (ab-income)
  (display "Income: ")
  (let ((income (string->number (read-line))))
    (if (or (not income) (<= income 600)) 
      (begin (display "Please enter an amount greater than $600.00\n\n")
             (ab-income))
      (begin (newline)
             (print-report 40 "Deduct for bills"       (* 3/10 income)
                              "Deduct for taxes"       (* 2/10 income)
                              "Deduct for savings"     (* 1/10 income)
                              "Remainder for checking" (* 4/10 income))))))
```

First, at least in my version of `mzscheme`, I needed a `(require (lib "string.ss"))` line to import `real->decimal-string`.  Next, I abstracted out the `display` block you were talking about.  What we see is that each line wants to print the money in the same format at the 40th column, printing a tag name and a row of dashes in front of it.  Consequently, I wrote `print-report`.  The first argument is the initial width; in this case, `40`.  The remaining arguments are field-value pairs.  The length of each field (plus two for the colon and the space) are subtracted from the width, and we generate a string consisting of that many dashes.  We use `format` to lay the fields out in the right order, and `display` to print the string.  The function recurses over all the pairs (using tail recursion, so we won't blow the stack).

In the main function, I moved the `(display "Income: ")` to before the `let`; you ignore its result, so why assign it to a variable?  I then augmented the `if` condition to test if `input` is false, which happens when `string->number` can't parse the input.  Finally, I removed your local variables, since all you do is print them, and used Scheme's fraction syntax instead of division.  (And of course, I use `print-report` instead of `display`s and `format`s.)

I think that's all; if you have any other questions about what I did, feel free to ask.

Comment: This was an excellent answer. Thank you so much - I got a good dose of theory and practical explanation; precisely (if not more) than what I had wanted.

Thank you very much!